# How can creatures with indestructible end up in the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

How does a creature with indestructible end up in the graveyard?

I have been trying to figure this out for a little while.

Answer (score 21):

Indestructible prevents the permanent from being destroyed.  This usually is caused by damage exceeding a creature's toughness, or an effect that explicitly says that it will destroy a permanent.

The main ways that a creature with indestructible will die (being put to the graveyard from the battlefield) will be:

1. Having its toughness reduced to zero via -X/-X effects. ([Tragic Slip](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTragic%20Slip%5d), [Black Sun's Zenith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%5d%2b%5bSun%27s%5d%2b%5bZenith%5d) or -1/-1 counters, including damage from a source with infect)
2. Being sacrificed. ([Innocent Blood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInnocent%20Blood%5d))
3. Losing indestructible and being destroyed ([Hour of Devastation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHour%20of%20Devastation%5d), [Turn to Frog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTurn%20to%20Frog%5d) + destruction effect)

Other ways to deal with indestructible permanents that do not cause them to "die" include:

1. Exiling. ([Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d))
2. Bounce. ([Unsummon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnsummon%5d))
3. Interacting with them on the stack. ([Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d))
4. Discard. ([Thoughtseize](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThoughtseize%5d))
5. Removal from the deck. ([Memoricide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMemoricide%5d))
6. Taking control of them. ([In Bolas's Clutches](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIn%5d%2b%5bBolas%27s%5d%2b%5bClutches%5d))
7. Move them to their owner's library. ([Condemn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=432990))

Comment: I would have linked to all the cards, but my current reputation won't allow it.

Comment: You can just write [mtg:<card name>] for card links.

Comment: Turning them frogs also works

Comment: Since the question calls out ending up in the graveyard, not just dying, it may be worth adding things like mill, self-mill, and discard.

Comment: The original question actually specified dying, though I am unsure that the person asking understand what that means in magic.  I tried to include ways to deal with indestructible creatures, as opposed to focusing on the graveyard itself.

Comment: Goblin Welder's current Oracle text calls for the player to sacrifice the artifact, which _suggests_ that being exchanged or placed into the graveyard is something they've tried to eliminate from the game, though I'm not sure if that's really the case.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that creature can temporarily lose indestructible and then die. ie with [Hour of Devastation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=430786) or [Burn from Within](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=409899)

Comment: Added that to the post.  Also, I removed the Goblin Welder example for the reasons David detailed.

Comment: I would add reference to infect and wither to "Having its toughness reduced to zero" just for more clarity.

Answer (score 4):

A creature with indestructible can die as a result of anything that is not damage ([Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt)) and does not explicitly use the word 'destroy' ([Doom Blade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Doom%20Blade)).

The most common ways:

Toughness reduced to less than zero.  (This is neither damage nor a 'destroy' effect.) e.g., [Death Wind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Death%20Wind)

The creature's controller is forced to sacrifice it.  e.g., [All is Dust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=All%20is%20Dust)

Comment: And of course, they can be exiled, returned to their owner's hand, or put back into their owner's library. None of that puts them in the graveyard, but it still gets rid of them!

Comment: It can also be discarded from hand or from the library.

Answer (score 2):

Damage dealt with infect is able to kill Indestructible creatures. This is because sources with infect deal damage to creatures in the form of -1/-1 counters, which eventually can reduce the creature's toughness to 0 or less.

Comment: The top answer already includes "reducing toughness to 0" -1/-1 counters and temporary -/- effects both work this way.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It is useful to mention that both Wither and Infect can cause indestructible creatures to go to the graveyard, but this answer would be a bit better suited as either an Edit to the existing answer or as a comment underneath it (You will be able to comment once you get a bit more Rep). Thanks for contributing though and hope you stick around.

Comment: I think infect/wither is worth mentioning separately.  Yes, this is a specific implementation of the Reducing Toughness category above, but both are achieved through damage, which is counter-intuitive for other cases of indestructability seemingly not caring about damage dealt.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I agree it should be mentioned, though not alone as a separate answer.

Comment: I've now included infect in the top voted answer.

Answer (score -6):

Lightning Bolt **is** damage, and does **not** affect indestructible.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked, it looks a lot more like a comment on Affe's answer based on a misreading of what Affe said (Lightning Bolt is used as an example of what is damage and thus will not work) When you have enough rep you'll be able to leave comments on questions and answers.